# System Config Multiselect default all selected

Tags: magento-1.9, system.xml, system-configuration, default-values

I have a system config field of type multiselect which will be populated using the `catalog/product_attribute_collection`. This is a part of the `system.xml` that defines it.

```
  <attributes>
       <label>Choose Attributes to JSONize</label>
       <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
       <sort_order>3</sort_order>
       <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
       <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
       <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

<source_model>package_module/system_config_attributes</source_model>
  </attributes>
```

Now I want all of the values in the multiselect to be selected by default. Since the default values for system config are defined in the `config.xml`, I'm not sure how to choose all as default.

This is the section of `config.xml` which is relevant to the question

```
<default>
    <mytab>
        <mysection>
            <attributes><!-- ***WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE*** --></attributes>
        </mysection>
    </mytab>
</default>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use D**ataScript** to store data in config module.

How to create data script

http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/

In datascript simply call the core **config module** and save your data

```
$myDynamicValue = '1,2,3';
Mage::getConfig()->saveConfig('section/group/field', $myDynamicValue, 'default', 0);
```

Comment: This was a really clever workaround, and it worked!

Answer (score 3):

I give multiselect example.

```
<fields>
    <view_style translate="label">
        <label>Display Settings</label>
        <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
        <source_model>yourmodule/system_config_source_view</source_model>
        <sort_order>40</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    </view_style>
</fields>
```

create one file for multiselect option in your module in this path

your_namespace/yourmodel/Model/System/Config/Source/View.php

Add below code in your View.php

```
class YourNamespace_YourModule_Model_System_Config_Source_View 
{
    /**
     * Options getter
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            array('value' => 0, 'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Data1')),
            array('value' => 1, 'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Data2')),
            array('value' => 2, 'label' => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Data3')),
        );
    }

    /**
     * Get options in "key-value" format
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {
        return array(
            0 => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Data1'),
            1 => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Data2'),
            3 => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('Data3'),
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer tells how to define a source model. I have done that already. I want all values from the source model to be selected by default

Answer (score 3):

```
<default>
     <mytab>
        <mysection>
            <attributes><!-- ***WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE*** --></attributes>
        </mysection>
    </mytab>
</default>
```

You should use the comma separated **keys** of your options array.

eg

```
<default>
     <mytab>
        <mysection>
            <attributes>0,1,3</attributes>
        </mysection>
    </mytab>
</default>
```

Selects all three options by default.

Comment: Yes but like I said.  I don't know the values beforehand to write in a comma-separated string. It's dynamic